# У меня стоит задача сделать написать код в Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно написать код который будет прибовлять числа Пример:я вписываю любое число на пример 5 - 1+2+3+4+5 и ответ, и я в ступоре , я новичек еще, пока не разобрался.

Comment: тоесть я пишу любое число на пример 3 и он прибовляет каждое тоесть 1+2+3 и ответ

Comment: `x = 3; print(sum(range(x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(sum(range(int(input('> ')) + 1)))
```